# Arithmetic Pointer and fstream C++

Tags: c++, pointers, stream

I am writing to a file, using a memory buffer. I copy each record to the memory buffer and then flush it to the disk.

CODE:

```
    char * OutBuffer;
    char *pt;
    OutBuffer = new char(BufferSize);
    pt = OutBuffer;

    for (int i=0; i<(FileSize / RECORD_SIZE); i++){
        if (((i % recordsPerBlock)==0) && (i>0)){
           FileSortHandle->write(OutBuffer, BufferSize);
           pt = OutBuffer;
        }
        else{
           memcpy(pt, minRecord, RECORD_SIZE);
           pt = pt + RECORD_SIZE;
        }
           minRecord = nullptr;
    }
```

When i call "FileSortHandle->write(OutBuffer, BufferSize);" the VS shows:

"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in STL_Test2.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in STL_Test2.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while STL_Test2.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information."

Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
OutBuffer = new char(BufferSize);
```

This allocates memory for just ONE char, and this one char is *initialized* with `BufferSize` which may cause overflow if `BufferSize` is too big for `char`.

What you probably meant is this:

```
OutBuffer = new char[BufferSize]; //use square brackets!
```

It allocates memory for `BufferSize` chars. The buffer is uninitialized.

---

It is not related to your problem, but if possible, prefer allocating the memory when you declare the pointer:

```
char * OutBuffer = new char [BufferSize];
char *pt = OutBuffer; //prefer initialization over assignment
```

That is, prefer initialization over assignment.

Comment: Did you mean "use square brackets"? Angle brackets look like this `<>`. These `[]` are square brackets.